# How to return value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return the value, i.e result of query.for the function below i am passing the product_id to get the product_name. so basically what i need to do is when i call this function i should be able to get the product_name as a return type which can be used somewhere else.

```
function getProductName($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_name FROM product_list where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<span>'. $row["product_name"].'</span>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    return $productName;    
}
```

for example:

```
$product_name = return getProductName(45);
```

i will get `numark mixtrack pro 2` that should be able to assigned to `$product_name;`

how can i do this?

Comment: Where do you set `$productName`?

Comment: What if the query returns more than one row? If it can't return more than one row, why are you using a loop to display the results?

Comment: **Dont change your question after it has been answered.** It makes the answers look foolish and destroys the ability for the question and answers to be useful to someone else later. _I have rolled back your question to its original state_

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an empty array and assign your product name to that

```
$productName=array();//creare an empty array
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $productName[]=$row["product_name"];// assing your product name to array
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    return $productName; // return your data
```

You can get your product name using

```
 $product_name =  getProductName(45);
 print_r($product_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getProductName($product_id)
{
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_name FROM product_list where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc() 
        $productName =  $row["product_name"];
    }
    else 
        echo "No results found";
    $conn->close(); 
    return $productName;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never setting `$productName` before you return it. You need to set it to `$row['product_name']`.

```
function getProductName($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_name FROM product_list where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row) {
        $productName = $row["product_name"];
        echo '<span>'. $productName.'</span>';
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
        $productName = "";
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    return $productName;    
}
```

There's no need for a `while` loop, since there can only be one product with an ID.

Comment: Thanks for recongnizing that i am not setting the variable..its working fine now.

Comment: When you're debugging, make sure you have error reporting enabled. You should have gotten a warning about accessing an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like this

```
function getProductName($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_name FROM product_list where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $htmlResult= '';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $htmlResult.= '<span>'. $row["product_name"].'</span>';
        }
    } else {
        $htmlResult = "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    return  $htmlResult;    
}
```

Comment: That will return the HTML, he just wants to return the product name.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

```
function getProductName($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_name FROM product_list where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc());
       $result= $row["product_name"];
    } 
    else {  $result = false;  }
    $conn->close(); 

   return $result;

}
```

use:

```
 $productName = getProductName(45);
 if ( $ProductName != false ) { echo '<span>'.$productName.'</span>'; } 
 else { echo 'No product found!!"; }
```

Comment: **What** and call a function that queries the database twice for no good reason. Please engage brain before logging on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks dude for guidance. I always remember this. :)